# iOS 11.3 - performSegue from ContainerViewController from parentViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent view `(with ViewController)` which has a sidebar menu and `containerView(ContainerViewController)` in it. at the `containerView`, I have 2 `segue` link with their own view and viewController (Screen1 with Screen1ViewController, Screen2 with Screen2ViewController).
[image]

I have buttons to launch `screen1` and `screen2` from `ViewController` but somehow the setting `performSegue()` function seems like not firing.

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var container : ContainerViewController!
    @IBOutlet var SideBar: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        container = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerViewController") as! ContainerViewController

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "tocontainer"{
            self.container = segue.destination as! ContainerViewController
        }
    }


    @IBAction func launchScreen1(_ sender: Any) {
        container.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toscreen1", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func launchScreen2(_ sender: Any) {
        container.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toscreen1", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

**ContainerViewController**

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func launchScreen2() {
        print("launchscreen2")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toscreen1", sender: self)
    }
}
```

As you can see i even tried a function `launchScreen2` for the button to call. the `print` message did appear in console but somehow no effect on the `self.performSegue`.

I believe is the way I prepare the segue is wrong, I just don't know what else to try.

Comment: Your buttons Are added in COntainerView and ContainerView is a Subview to your ViewController if you want to work with button added in Container View , first you need to get control in ViewController to navigate this is Valid for case if segued screen is not to be displayed in containerView

Comment: if you want to make screenSegue and Destination to show in same Controller you need to take all this control in VC added as a Subview in Container View and After selecting any data from Destination VC make use of protocols

Comment: I want the button in the sidebar, which is in `ParentViewController` so that whenever `containerView` perform segue, it will not replace the `sidebar`.

Comment: its like you want to perform segue inside containerView ? but button action in ParentView Controller ?

Comment: try checking https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git , do this repo Helps you achieving required task ?